# MVC - FormsAuthentication Get the RoleName

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and learning how to custom Roles using FormAuthentication from this tutorial [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/578374/AplusBeginner-splusTutorialplusonplusCustomplusF)

This code below is stored the Roles. It works fine when I perform this `[Authorize(Roles="admin")]` in the controller

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FormsAuthentication.CookiesSupported == true)
    {
        if (Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] != null)
        {
            try
            {
                //let us take out the username now                
                string username = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value).Name;
                string roles = string.Empty;

                using (userDbEntities entities = new userDbEntities())
                {
                    User user = entities.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.username == username);

                    roles = user.Roles;
                }
                //let us extract the roles from our own custom cookie


                //Let us set the Pricipal with our user specific details
                HttpContext.Current.User  = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(
                  new System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity(username, "Forms"), roles.Split(';'));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //somehting went wrong
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get the actual Role Name based on the current User.Identity? like below pseudo-code.

```
[Authorize]    
public ActionResult Index()
{
    bool isAdmin = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("admin");  // This also works correctly.
    Response.Write("role: " + isAdmin);

    string roleName = // The Code of How to get the actual Role Name
    Response.Write("roleName: " + roleName);  //e.g Admin, User...

    return View();
}
```

Comment: There is not build-in method to list out all roles from `HttpContext.Current.User`. Besides, `FormsAuthentication` is a pretty old technology, and it has been replaced by `OWIN cookie authentication middleware` in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @Win, Thanks for reply.  Do you know any good article about OWIN cookie authentication for custom table for username and roles?

Comment: Since there is no build-in method to get the roles, anyone knows a work-around to get the role name?  Or I should query the database User table and store the Role Name in the session when user is logging in?

Answer (score 1):

> From Comment: *Do you know any good article about OWIN cookie
>   authentication for custom table for username and roles?*

It has few pieces, so I created a sample project in GitHub [AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin). *The original souce is to authenticate with AD, but you just need to modify [ActiveDirectoryService](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web.Common/Security/ActiveDirectoryService.cs) class where you query custom tables.*

The following three are the main classes -

1. [AccountController](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web/Controllers/AccountController.cs)
2. [ActiveDirectoryService](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web.Common/Security/ActiveDirectoryService.cs)
3. [OwinAuthenticationService](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web.Common/Security/OwinAuthenticationService.cs) replaces FormsAuthentication.

Comment: It looks so complicated, but I will look into it.  Thank you for that.